# How do we check container logs in kubernetes before they are written to the log file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

`kubectl logs -f <pod-name>`

This command shows the logs from the container log file.

Basically, I want to check the difference between "what is generated by the container" and "what is written to the log file".
I see some unusual binary logs, so I just want to find out if the container is creating those binary logs or the logs are not properly getting written to the log file.

"Unusual logs":

`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\`

Answer (score 4):

Usually, containerized applications, do not write to the log files but send messages to `stdout`/`stderr`, there is no point in storing log files inside containers, as they will be deleted when the pod is deleted.
What you see when running

```
kubectl logs -f <pod-name>
```

are messages sent to `stdout`/`stderr`. There are no container specific logs here, only application logs.

---

If, for some reason, your application does write to the log file, you can check it by `exec`ing into pod with e.g.

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/bash
```

and read logs as you would in shell.

## Edit

### Application logs

A container engine handles and redirects any output generated to a containerized application's `stdout` and `stderr` streams. For example, the Docker container engine redirects those two streams to a [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/), which is configured in Kubernetes to write to a file in JSON format.
Those logs are also saved to

- `/var/log/containers/`
- `/var/log/pods/`

By default, if a container restarts, the kubelet keeps one terminated container with its logs. If a pod is evicted from the node, all corresponding containers are also evicted, along with their logs.

Everything you see by issuing the command

```
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```

is what application sent to `stdout`/`stderr`, or what was redirected to `stdout`/`stderr`. For example `nginx`:

> The official nginx image creates a symbolic link from `/var/log/nginx/access.log` to `/dev/stdout`, and creates another symbolic link from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to `/dev/stderr`, overwriting the log files and causing logs to be sent to the relevant special device instead.

### Node logs

Components that do not run inside containers (e.g kubelet, container runtime) write to `journald`. Otherwise, they write to `.log` fies inside `/var/log/` directory.

*Excerpt from [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs):*

For now, digging deeper into the cluster requires logging into the relevant machines. Here are the locations of the relevant log files. (note that on systemd-based systems, you may need to use journalctl instead)

**Master**

- `/var/log/kube-apiserver.log` - API Server, responsible for serving the API
- `/var/log/kube-scheduler.log` - Scheduler, responsible for making scheduling decisions
- `/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log` - Controller that manages replication controllers

**Worker Nodes**

- `/var/log/kubelet.log` - Kubelet, responsible for running containers on the node
- `/var/log/kube-proxy.log` - Kube Proxy, responsible for service load balancing

Comment: With `kubectl logs` command we can even see an hour old logs. So, it must be storing it somewhere, right?
In my case logs are being written to /var/logs/ directory in the kubernetes node. Still not sure if `kubectl logs` command would read the logs from the log file or `stderr / stdout`.

Comment: I edited and expanded my previous answer. See if it answers you question.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to check log is kubernets:

=> If pod have single container

```
kubectl logs POD_NAME
```

=> If pod have multiple containers

```
kubectl logs POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME -n NAMESPACE
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could imagine this to work is to make use of some external logging facility like Syslog or Elastisearch or anything else. Configure your application to send logs directly to logging facility (avoiding agents like fluentd or logstash which parse logs from files).

All modern languages have support for external logging. You can also [configure](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/syslog/) Docker to send logs to syslog server.